# No module named '_curses'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, curses

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\the stuff\DarkOS-main\bootscreen.py", line 21, in <module>
    from curses import *
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 
13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
```

How do you get `'_curses'` on windows?

Some code:

```py
from curses import *
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple. You need to install the library by running
`pip install windows-curses`

You could type the above command in command prompt for Vscode or on the terminal in Pycharm